# Savon create matched XML pattern

Tags: ruby, soap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, savon

I am trying to get the pan info from the income tax of india web API.

The standard XML for the request is this

```
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:pan="http://panws.dit.tcs.com/" xmlns:typ="http://panws.dit.tcs.com/types/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
        <pan:getPanInfo>
          <login>
             <typ:userName>xxxxxxxxx</typ:userName>
             <typ:password>xxxxxxxxxx</typ:password>
          </login>
          <panNo>
             <typ:panNo>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</typ:panNo>
          </panNo>
          </pan:getPanInfo>
         </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am using SAVON ruby gem to submit the request in the above format. My code is

```
        client = Savon.client do |globals|
           globals.wsdl 'https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-FilingWS/ditws/PanWS.wsdl'
        end
        client.call(:get_pan_info, message: {
           "login" => {
               "typ:userName" => "xxxxxxxxxx",
               "typ:password" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
             }, 
             "panNo" => {
             "typ:panNo" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        })
```

It creates the XML to be submitted is here:

```
    <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://panws.dit.tcs.com/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins0="http://panws.dit.tcs.com/types/">
   <env:Body>
     <tns:getPanInfo>
        <tns:login>
           <typ:userName>xxxxxxx</typ:userName>
            <typ:password>xxxxxxxxxxxx</typ:password>
        </tns:login>
        <tns:panNo>
           <typ:panNo>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</typ:panNo>
        </tns:panNo>
      </tns:getPanInfo>
     </env:Body>
   </env:Envelope>
```

and it gives 500 External server Error,

Can any body please point me out where i am wrong or how to create the same XML for the request.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the correct `env_namespace` :

```
Savon.client(env_namespace: :soapenv)
```

`Ctrl+F` for `env_namespace` [here](http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html)

Comment: How can I replace this <tns:getPanInfo> with <pan:getPanInfo>

Comment: and also <tns:login> with <login>

Comment: To replace `<tns:login>` with `<login>` simply use `Savon.client(element_form_default :unqualified)`. The default body namespace is to be set by `savon` internally, according to your `wsdl` provided. If it does not, that possibly means that the wsdl is somehow misunderstood by savon. In such a case you are to create the `request` by hands. [More info](http://fagiani.github.io/savon/#executing_soap_requests).